# Loading table dynamically with Angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm trying to load a table dynamically from a json, but I have a problem to go through two lists before the tag `<th>` and `<td>`.

In the example below I am using the  just to simulate what I would do.

**Json**

```
"Tables": [
{
  "ID": "1",
  "Title": "Table 1",
  "Rows": [
    {
      "ID": "1",
      "Title": "Row 1",
      "Columns": [
        {
          "ID": "1",
          "Title": "Column 1",
          "Type": "RADIO",
          "SubColumns": [
            {
              "ID": "1",
              "Title": "A",
              "Value": ""
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}]
```

**HTML**

```
<div data-ng-repeat="table in Tables">
    <table class="table table-condensed">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th rowspan="2" style="vertical-align: middle; width: 30%">
                    {{table.Title}}
                </th>
                <span data-ng-repeat="column in table.Rows[0].Columns">
                    <th colspan="column.SubColumns.length" style="text-align: center">
                        {{column.Title}}
                    </th>
                </span>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <span data-ng-repeat="column in table.Rows[0].Columns">
                    <th data-ng-repeat="subColumn in column.SubColumns">
                        {{subColumn.Title}}
                    </th>
                </span>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr data-ng-repeat="row in table.Rows">
                <td>
                    {{row.Title}}
                </td>

                <span data-ng-repeat="column in row.Columns">
                    <span data-ng-if="column.Type == 'TEXT'">
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" />
                        </td>
                    </span>
                    <span data-ng-if="column.Type == 'RADIO'">
                        <td data-ng-repeat="subColumn in column.SubColumns">
                            <input type="radio" />
                        </td>
                    </span>
                    <span data-ng-if="column.Type == 'CHECKBOX'">
                        <td data-ng-repeat="subColumn in column.SubColumns">
                            <input type="checkbox" />
                        </td>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Does anyone have any idea to solve this problem?

Thank's

Comment: Why do you use spans? They're invalid inside a tr. Put the ng-repeat directly on the th or the td. Put the ng-if inside the th or the td.

Comment: I used the span only simulate the idea I wanted to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point, I don't believe ng-repeat supports iterating over nested arrays with a single directive.

The only way I've been able to solve this is to flatten out the nested arrays first.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th ng-repeat="column in data[0].Rows[0].Columns" colspan="{{column.SubColumns.length}}">
        {{column.Title}}
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th ng-repeat="subcol in flattenedSubcols()">
        {{subcol.Title}}
      </th>
    </tr> 
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="row in data[0].Rows">
      <td data-ng-repeat="data in flattenedRowData(row)">{{data}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Flattening functions

```
  $rootScope.flattenedSubcols = function() {
    var subcolumns = [];
    $rootScope.data[0].Rows[0].Columns.forEach(function(col) {
      col.SubColumns.forEach(function(subcol) {
        subcolumns.push(subcol);
      });
    });
    return subcolumns; 
  };


  $rootScope.flattenedRowData = function(row) {
    var data = [];
    row.Columns.forEach(function(col) {
      col.SubColumns.forEach(function(subcol) {
        data.push(subcol.Value);
      });
    });
    return data;
  };
```

This feels a bit hacky, but it does the job

Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/HLCYkkSBfR95jd6PoutW

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling the iterator of columns like this:

```
column in table.Rows[0].Columns
```

Try this way:

```
column in table.Rows[$index].Columns
```